# Datatable sorting jQuery by parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Yo guys, im working on some project that contains datatable,

The datatable working by ajax that returns json and inserting all data to the table for example :

```
ID   NAME     ROLE     CITY         ADDRESS
----------------------------------------------------------
 2   ALBERT   ADMIN    Albany       CenterStreet
 3   AMBER    USER     BurrRidge    AintreeLane
 4   NICOLE   ADMIN    BurrRidge    AintreeLane
 5   MARY     USER     Albany       Broadway
 6   SHELLY   USER     Albany       CenterStreet
```

I'm trying to sort the table so when I click a button it will toggle the sort for all admins to the first rows, so it will show albert and nicole first but if press one more button that called "Albany" it will show ALBERT in the first row cause he had those to parameters, but when i click to toggle CenterStreet albert will be in first and shelly after him cause she is in Albany and CenterStreet even she is not an admin.

I've tried some ways of doing this, but unfortunately no success, does any one know how to do this kind of thing with datatables on jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to sort the jsonobject.

```
var ja = [{id:1,name:XYZ},{id:2,name:ABC}];
var asc = true;
var prop = 'id';
sort(ja,prop,asc);


function sort(properties, prop, asc) {
        properties = properties.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            } else {
                return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            }
        });
        return properties;
    }
```